# How to check if date of year has passed using Carbon/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In Laravel, I'm trying to check if the current date is before or after a specific date in **any year**. A client's fiscal year ends October 31st and I'm having trouble checking if today is before or after that.

I've tried using the built in comparison functions in Carbon but I can't figure out what to compare `now()` with, since all Carbon instances seems to include a specific year. How do I check if `now()` has passed that day in **any** calender year?

The code below works but using `dayOfYear()` will return different values on leap years and seems like a poor solution.

```php
if (now()->dayOfYear >= 304) {
    $current_year = now()->year;
} else {
    $current_year = now()->year - 1;
}
```

How can I return true if `now()` is after October 31st in any year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you already know about using [getters with the Carbon object](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) to find pieces of the date. If you're looking to see if the current date is after October 31, just use them some more:

```php
if (now()->month > 10) {
    $current_year = now()->year;
} else {
    $current_year = now()->subYear()->year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the current date is before any given date

```php
$isBefore31October = now()->lt(Carbon::parse('2020-10-31'));

//Will return false if now() occurs after 31st October 2020
```

Similarly to check if the current date occurs after a given date

```php
$isAfter31October = now()->gt(Carbon::parse('2020-10-31'));

//Will return true if now() occurs after 31st October 2020
```

For setting the current year depending upon whether current date occurs after 31st October of current year

```php
$fyEnd = Carbon::parse(now()->year . "-10-31");

$current_year = now()->gt($fyEnd) ? now()->year : now()->year - 1;
```